# Linearization of VES production funtions

Tags: production-function, elasticity-of-substitution, aggregate-production

I know that the linearization of a CES (constant elasticity of substitution) funtion is a bit complicated. There is even an R package dedicated just for that - the econometric estimation and calculation of a CES function (of wich Cobb-Douglas, Leontief and linear production functions are special cases) - micEconCES. However, I can't find anything about the econometric estimation of a VES (variable elasticity of substitution) production function.

---

Is it (linearisation and/or econometric estimation) possible at all, or do the characteristics of the function not permit linearisation?

---

P.S. I'm aware that there are different forms of the VES function.

Comment: It would be good if you included in your post a specific exaple of a VES function.